# Telegram login widget doesn't work in inApp browser before ios10

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Use [telegram login widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) to do the OAuth, it works fine in most of the browsers even in mobile. But it can't work in inApp browser, even in Telegram its own mobile App inline browser.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Click the link in telegram mobile app on `ios 10`, `ios 9`, You can copy this link and click it in Telegram: https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login
2. Scroll down and you will find the login button, and click it to login via telegram

**Expected Result:** It will popup the alert or redirect to the url you set.

**Actually Result:** It will suck at the oauth page.

And checked the `user-agent` in Telegram inline browser, it's same as the actually browser. [Detect User-Agent](http://www.fed.tw/detect-inapp/).

Comment: Do you already have any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Not yet, currently we only record the user's OS version to guess it, and promote the user with some warning message.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need https bot domain.

I tired http, its works on desktop but not works on mobile.

Then I tried https, its works as expected on mobile like the example at https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login

PS I tested with Safari@iPad-iOS13 and firefox@iPhoneiOS12